# Altiris Deployment Console and PXE booting over multiple vlans

Tags: deployment, hp, pxe-boot, configuration-management

I am rebuilding a 2008 server with sql 2008 and altiris Deployment console 6.9 sp2. It is working now however I am trying to get the clients to be able to pxe boot and load an image from altiris no matter which vlan they are on.  We have about 8 vlans each with its own DHCP scope and using hp procurve switches for the acls and the core switch does all the layer 3 work. Has anybody acheived this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't have any experience with Altiris, but normally you would configure the Layer 3 device to forward BOOTP/DHCP/PXE requests to an IP address (in this case you DHCP server and deployment server).

On a Cisco switch this is configured using IP HELPER ADDRESS.

Comment: Yep thanks this worked, the command is the same for hp procurve switches.  The only problem I face is that some of the other vlans are already using the ip helper command on them and they are for a different dhcp server so I am going to integrate both answers have two nics on 2 subnets that should cover all angles. Thanks guys

Answer (score 1):

I've not done this, so this is just my musings.

Give the 2008 server multiple static ip addresses and assign mutiple VLANS to the port that it plugs into.

Make sure the 2008 server doesn't try to bridge any traffic.

Comment: To add to this, If you add option 60 to your DHCP server wih PXEClient as the value.
You can do this by the netsh command line.
Then on all the vlans set the helper address as listed above and done.